# Register new grunt task to work with a supplied target

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My Gruntfile defines 3 targets "dev", "beta", and "production" across several tasks. If I run `grunt task:target` it works correctly for that task.

Now I want to combine all my tasks into a single build task. I tried:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['task1', 'task2', 'task3']);
```

but if I run `grunt build:dev`, it ignores my target and simply runs all targets for all the build tasks.

This works:

```
grunt.registerTask('build:dev', ['task1:dev', 'task2:dev', 'task3:dev']);
grunt.registerTask('build:beta', ['task1:beta', 'task2:beta', 'task3:beta']);
grunt.registerTask('build:production', ['task1:production', 'task2:production', 'task3:production']);
```

But I'm sure it's not the correct way, nor does it scale well.

I was able to do what I wanted with this:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', 'My build task', function(targetName) {

    runTask('task1', targetName);
    runTask('task2', targetName);
    runTask('task3', targetName);

});

function runTask(task, targetName) {

    if (targetName) {
        grunt.task.run(task + ':' + targetName);
    } else
    {
        grunt.task.run(task);
    }
}
```

It works, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something already built into Grunt to accomplish the same.